# How to allign imageview spacing equally in relativelayout android?

Tags: android, android-layout

My doubt is how to allign the imageview and textview spacing equally inside the relativelayout or anyother layout i tried but couldn't succeed in it let me post my code what i have tried so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    tools:context=".Activities.VisitView"
    android:background="#e3e3e3">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:background="#e3e3e3"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:background="#fff"
      android:layout_margin="20dp"
      android:id="@+id/child"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"

       android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
         android:id="@+id/e"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_downloads"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Download"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/e"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/first"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/second">
      <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
          android:id="@+id/e1"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_up_arrow"/>
      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Upload"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

          android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
          android:textSize="12sp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
          android:layout_below="@+id/e1"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
      <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/second"
          android:id="@+id/third">
          <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
              android:id="@+id/e3"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              android:src="@drawable/ic_up_arrow"/>
          <TextView
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Print"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

              android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
              android:textSize="12sp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
              android:layout_below="@+id/e3"/>

      </RelativeLayout>
      <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/third"
          android:id="@+id/four">
          <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
              android:id="@+id/e4"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              android:src="@drawable/ic_up_arrow"/>
          <TextView
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Notes"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

              android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
              android:textSize="12sp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
              android:layout_below="@+id/e4"/>

      </RelativeLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_below="@+id/child"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:id="@+id/visit"
      android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
      android:divider="#e3e3e3"
      android:keepScreenOn="true"
      android:scrollbars="vertical"
      android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
      />

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

But the textview and imageview not alligned inside the relative layout properly this is the image [image]

How to allign this image and textview properly Thanks in advance!!

Comment: try use `LinearLayout` with `weight`

Comment: you can't do that because your text is different. for this you have to set fix height width of Relativelayout

Comment: yes @PhanVanLinh right. you can also use Main LinearLayout with weightSum and inner LinearLayout with weight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:background="#e3e3e3">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#e3e3e3"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/child"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/first"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/e"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_up_arrow" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/e"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Download"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/second"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/e1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_up_arrow" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/e1"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Upload"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/third"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/e3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_up_arrow" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/e3"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Print"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/four"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/e4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_up_arrow" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/e4"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Notes"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/visit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/child"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:divider="#e3e3e3"
                android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
                android:keepScreenOn="true"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
android:background="#e3e3e3">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:background="#e3e3e3"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/child"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/first"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/e"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/inactive_settings"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Download"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/e"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/first"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/second">
            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/e1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/inactive_settings"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Upload"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/e1"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/second"
            android:id="@+id/third">
            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/e3"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/inactive_settings"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Print"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/e3"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/third"
            android:id="@+id/four">
            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/e4"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/inactive_settings"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Notes"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/e4"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/child"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/visit"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:divider="#e3e3e3"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e3e3e3"
    tools:context=".Activities.VisitView">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#e3e3e3"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/child"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/first"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/e"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_downloads" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/e"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Download"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/second"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/first"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/e1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_up_arrow" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/e1"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Upload"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/third"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/second"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/e3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_up_arrow" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/e3"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Print"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/four"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/third"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/e4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_up_arrow" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/e4"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Notes"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/visit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/child"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:divider="#e3e3e3"
            android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
            android:keepScreenOn="true"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LinearLayout with the weight sum:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:background="#e3e3e3"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/child"
            android:weightSum="4"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/first"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/e"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_downloads"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Download"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/e"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/first"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/second">
                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/e1"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_up_arrow"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Upload"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/e1"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/second"
                android:id="@+id/third">
                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/e3"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_up_arrow"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Print"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/e3"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/third"
                android:id="@+id/four">
                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/e4"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_up_arrow"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Notes"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/e4"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/child"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/visit"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:divider="#e3e3e3"
            android:keepScreenOn="true"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this, implement the linear layout inside the relative layout.Place your image view in place of my image view in Relative layout.

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/tv"
        android:id="@+id/starImage" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/music"
        android:id="@+id/callImage" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/books"
        android:id="@+id/shareImage" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/block_icon"
        android:id="@+id/blockImage" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/edit"
        android:id="@+id/deleteimage" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Your output will lokk like this.

[image]